# HttpWebRequest creates request on Non-KeepAlive pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httpwebrequest

I've been facing a unique problem for a while now. Our web servers runs under constant load (approx 500 Request Per Second) throughout the day. And we also make outbound call our external API.

Problem:
I see about 9k-10k TIME_WAIT connections to my external API (I applied filter on netstat)
Even though TIME_WAIT recycles after 30 seconds(yes, we changed in registry); under constant load;  our server throughput reduces because we run into port exhaustion (I can increase the port numbers, but I want to fix the problem first)

1. We throttle connection to our external API. We've set MaxConnection to 16 after numerous load test under the same RPS. AutoConfig is also set to false.
2. We want to maintain Keep-Alive connections so that we can reuse the channel.

What's happening:
1. Server stays healthy for sometime, and throttles connections. But after a while, for some reason i start to get exponential TIME_WAIT. I've noticed that when Server goes bad (lot of TIME_WAIT); it creates every new connection on Non-KeepAlive pipeline. I say this because ESTABLISHED connection are on new port everytime we hit netstat. it does not reuse the channel.
Moreover, wireshark also shows that my web server explicitly send Connection:Close header to external API and hence it then sends FIN pack and goes into TIME_WAIT state.

What have we to tried so far:
Almost everything that MS recommended, did not work. We finally started creating unique ConnectionGroupName per minute. So that after a minute all connections from old group gets recycled. This did fix the problem in our Load Test environment. however, no result in production setup. We've replicated the load test environment exactly like production with lower number of instances ofcourse.

Has anyone encountered such problem before? The main problem is that once the server goes in endless TIME_WAIT state, it cannot recover; we tried to pull it out from ELB, it does recycle the connections but once we put it back on, it goes bad within seconds.

We're using Windows Server 2008 R2 and .net framework 4.5.1

Any help would be appreciated..